# How to interactively display and hide lines in a Bokeh plot?

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

It would be nice to be able to interactively display and hide lines in a bokeh plot. Say, I have created my plot something like this:

```
from bokeh.plotting import output_file, figure, show
from numpy.random import normal, uniform

meas_data_1 = normal(0, 1, 100)
meas_data_2 = uniform(-0.5, 0.5, 100)

output_file("myplot.html", title="My plot")
fig = figure(width=500, plot_height=500)

fig.line(x=range(0, len(meas_data_1)), y=meas_data_1)
fig.line(x=range(0, len(meas_data_2)), y=meas_data_2)

show(fig)
```

How can I add the possibility to interactively enable/disable one of the two lines?

I know that this is on the wish list (see [this feature request](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/2274)), but that doesn't sound like it would be implemented too soon.

I have the impression that this should be possible using a [CheckBoxGroup](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#checkbox-group) and a [self-defined callback](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#callbacks-for-widgets), but unfortunately this callback has to be written in JavaScript, which I have absolutely no experience in.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**EDIT**: Interactive legends are now built into the library as of Bokeh `0.12.5`, see https://bokeh.github.io/blog/2017/4/5/release-0-12-5/

---

This appears on track to be implemented at some point as interactive legends:
https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3715

Currently (v0.12.1), there is an example that uses CustomJS on checkboxes to achieve this:
https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/4868

Relevant code:

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis3
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import CheckboxGroup, CustomJS

output_file("line_on_off.html", title="line_on_off.py example")

p = figure()
props = dict(line_width=4, line_alpha=0.7)
x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 100)
l0 = p.line(x, np.sin(x), color=Viridis3[0], legend="Line 0", **props)
l1 = p.line(x, 4 * np.cos(x), color=Viridis3[1], legend="Line 1", **props)
l2 = p.line(x, np.tan(x), color=Viridis3[2], legend="Line 2", **props)

checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=["Line 0", "Line 1", "Line 2"],
                         active=[0, 1, 2], width=100)
checkbox.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(l0=l0, l1=l1, l2=l2, checkbox=checkbox),
                             lang="coffeescript", code="""
l0.visible = 0 in checkbox.active;
l1.visible = 1 in checkbox.active;
l2.visible = 2 in checkbox.active;
""")

layout = row(checkbox, p)
show(layout)
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Side question: is there a way to do this using a list of renderers instead of separate variables? I'd like to show/hide a set of ~30 different renderers at once.

Comment: Probably, you should be able to pass a list as one of the values in the `args`  dict, IIRC.

Comment: Couldn't get that to work, bokeh raised `ValueError: expected an element of Dict(String, Instance(Model)), got {'renderers': [<bokeh.models.renderers.GlyphRenderer object at 0x11db30090>, ...], 'checkbox': <bokeh.models.widgets.groups.CheckboxButtonGroup object at 0x11c4adc90>}`

Comment: For a workaround, I gave each renderer that I wanted to be able to interactively hide the `name="hideable"`. Then instead of a list of renderers, I passed `plot=p` into the `args` dict. My coffeescript code was then: `rends = plot.select("hideable"); 
rends[i].visible = i in checkbox.active for i in [0...rends.length];`

Comment: Ah, sending simple containers might not be too hard to implement, if you want to make a GH feature request (no guarantees about when it might be addressed)

Comment: In Bokeh 0.12.3, use the `.from_coffeescript` method instead of `lang="coffeescript"`

Comment: As of 0.12.5 you just use `plot.legend.click_policy = "hide"` and you're done.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Needed to remove lang="coffeescript" to make it work in my case.

Comment: For version 3.1.0 scripting has slightly changed, please refer to https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/examples/plotting/line_on_off.html

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong, but it seems to me that there is no id available for the various lines, one way of hiding them would have been to do a `document.getElementById("idSelected").style.visibility = "hidden";`

since `CheckBoxGroup` doesn't have a callback available I decided to use a `Select`.
I can get the selected source in the `CustomJS`, but that's pretty much all :

```
from bokeh.io import vform
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Select
from bokeh.plotting import output_file, figure, show
from numpy.random import normal, uniform

meas_data_1 = normal(0, 1, 10)
meas_data_2 = uniform(-0.5, 0.5, 10)

x1 = range(0, len(meas_data_1))
y1 = meas_data_1
source1 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x1, y=y1))
x2 = range(0, len(meas_data_2))
y2 = meas_data_2
source2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x2, y=y2))



output_file("myplot.html", title="My plot")
fig = figure(width=500, plot_height=500)

fig.line('x', 'y', source=source1, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)
fig.line('x', 'y', source=source2, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

select = Select(title="Option:", options=["source1", "source2"])

select.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source1=source1, source2=source2, select=select), code="""

        console.log(select.attributes.value);
    """)



show(vform(fig, select))
```

Maybe you can "tweak" the data in the `CustomJS` making it all 0 depending on what is selected, or maybe if you can access the line_width property and make it 0, but that's pretty much all I can think of.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, the new answer re `0.12.1` reflects the most current information / new features to make this much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

```
fig.legend.click_policy="hide"
```

Click on legend and hide or show the line.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).